# Java method is not applicable for the arguments ERROR

Tags: java, string, object, types

im writing a program and get this type of error:

The method orElse(Integer) in the type Maybe is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Another error i get is: cannot convert from Object to String in

```
   msg = Maybe.of(txt)
               .filter(t -> t.length() > 0)
               .orElse("Txt is null or empty");
```

Also, I'm not entirely sure if the methods orElse() and filter() are working correctly, but I am unable to move forward with this error appearing. Thanks for help in advance.

This is my Main:

```
package Maybe;


public class Main {

  public static void test() {

    Integer num = null;

    // orElse() METHOD
    // INSTEAD OF
    String snum = null;
    if (num != null) snum = "Value is: " + num;
    if (snum != null) System.out.println(snum);
    else System.out.println("Value unavailable");

//    //ONE CAN WRITE
//    String res = Maybe.of(num).map(n -> "Value is: "+n)
//                      .orElse("Value unavailable");
//    System.out.println(res);

    //filter(...) METHOD

    String txt = "Dog";
    String msg = "";
    //INSTEAD OF
    if (txt != null && txt.length() > 0) {
      msg = txt;
    } else {
      msg = "Txt is null or empty";
    }

    //ONE CAN WRITE
//    msg = Maybe.of(txt)
//               .filter(t -> t.length() > 0)
//               .orElse("Txt is null or empty"); 
//    System.out.println(msg);


  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    test();
  }
}
```

And my Maybe class:

```
package Maybe;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Maybe<T> {

    T cont;

    public Maybe(T val) {
        this.cont = val;
    }

    public Maybe() {
    }

    public static <T> Maybe <T> of(T val) {
        Maybe <T> m = new Maybe<T>(val);        
        return m;
    }

    public void ifPresent(Consumer<T> cons) {
        if(isPresent()) {
            cons.accept(get());
        }
    }

    public <R> Maybe <T> map(Function<T, R> func) {
        Maybe<T> mb = new Maybe();
        if(isPresent()) {
            mb = new Maybe(func.apply(get()));
        }
        return mb;
    }

    public T get(){     
        if(isPresent()) {
            return this.cont;
        } else {
            NoSuchElementException exc = new NoSuchElementException("maybe is empty");
            throw exc;
        }
    }

    public boolean isPresent() {
        if(this.cont != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public T orElse(T defVal) {
        if(isPresent()) {
            return get();
        }
        return defVal;
    }

    public Maybe filter(Predicate pred) {
        if(pred.test(pred) || !isPresent()) {
            return this;
        } else {
            Maybe mb = new Maybe();
            return mb;
        }
    }



    public String toString() {
        if(isPresent()) {
            return "Maybe has value " + cont;
        }else {
            return "Maybe is empty";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Error is correct as `orElse` return type is of type `T` which in your case is `Integer`. (Integer num)

Comment: You can avoid this in the future if you turn on all compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Maybe filter(Predicate pred)
```

Your `filter` method takes a [raw](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html) predicate and returns a raw `Maybe`.

That means it's expecting a predicate that will work for any object, and it gives a `Maybe` that might contain any type of object.

It should be something like

```
public Maybe<T> filter(Predicate<? super T> pred) {
    if (isPresent() && !pred.test(cont)) {
        return new Maybe<T>();
    }
    return this;
}
```

So it will only accept a predicate that works for the generic type `T`, and it returns a `Maybe` that can only contain an object of type `T`.

---

Also your `map` function is wrong.

```
public <R> Maybe <T> map(Function<T, R> func)
```

This assumes that after your `T` has had `func` applied to it, you will have a `Maybe<T>`. But you would actually have a `Maybe<R>`, because `R` is what `func` produces.

This would make more sense:

```
public <R> Maybe<R> map(Function<T, R> func) {
    if (isPresent()) {
        return new Maybe<R>(func.apply(cont));
    }
    return new Maybe<R>();
}
```

---

Here is the code working:

```
jshell> String txt = "Hi";
txt ==> "Hi"

jshell> String msg = Maybe.of(txt).filter(t -> t.length() > 0).orElse("Empty");
msg ==> "Hi"

jshell> txt = "";
txt ==> ""

jshell> msg = Maybe.of(txt).filter(t -> t.length() > 0).orElse("Empty");
msg ==> "Empty"
```

Comment: That helped, but still i get an ClassCastException error.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to add the stack trace for your exception to your question, along with the piece of code that caused it.

Comment: Stack trace:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Maybe.Main$$Lambda$5/1149319664 cannot be cast to java.lang.String

And this causes the error:
msg = Maybe.of(txt).
filter(t -> t.length() > 0)
.orElse("Txt is null or empty");
System.out.println(msg);

Comment: Thanks a lot, functions and predicates still confuse me, but your explanation helped a lot! Thanks!